# SSO using SAML with Spring Security for REST service

Tags: java, spring, security, single-sign-on, saml

I have a REST service on Spring Boot and now need to add SSO using SAML into it. I'm a new on SAML / Spring Security and trying to understand main pieces which need to add into the my application.

My IT provided metadata file:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor ID="Lusm3k0_RWEBKgnQ" cacheDuration="PT1440M" entityID="XXX.UAT.SAML2.0"
                 xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
<md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                     WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
                    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
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:ArtifactResolutionService index="0" Location="https://SITE-XXX.com/idp/ARS.ssaml2"
                                  Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" isDefault="true"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                            Location="https://SITE-XXX.com/idp/SLO.saml2"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                            Location="https://SITE-XXX.com/idp/SLO.saml2"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"
                            Location="https://SITE-XXX.com/idp/SLO.saml2"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
                            Location="https://SITE-XXX.com/idp/SLO.ssaml2"/>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                            Location="https://SITE-XXX.com/idp/SSO.saml2"/>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                            Location="https://SITE-XXX.com/idp/SSO.saml2"/>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"
                            Location="https://SITE-XXX.com/idp/SSO.saml2"/>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
                            Location="https://SITE-XXX.com/idp/SSO.saml2"/>
    <saml:Attribute Name="email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
<md:AttributeAuthorityDescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:AttributeService Location="https://SITE-XXX.com/idp/attrsvc.ssaml2"
                         Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"/>
</md:AttributeAuthorityDescriptor>
<md:ContactPerson contactType="administrative">
    <md:Company>XXX, Inc.</md:Company>
    <md:GivenName>Global</md:GivenName>
    <md:SurName>Directory Services</md:SurName>
    <md:EmailAddress>IAM_SSO_Ops@XXX.com</md:EmailAddress>
</md:ContactPerson>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

in pom.xml I added dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M31</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I configure and use this metadata for Spring SAML? How the configuration files should looks like?
I need just simplest case, where /** all REST points is secured.

The solutions which I googled in internet didn't use such kind of metadata and I do not understand how properly use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of learning curve for SAML, as it contains many terminologies. End to end example may not be possible here, but I can tell you how it works.

The xml provided by your Admin is the federation metadata of your IdP. In SAML, both SAML Service Provier and SAML IdP exchange their metadata, either through xml files or as a service which returns this xml content.
Federation metadata contains information such as signing/encryption certs, endpoint information, protocols supported, etc.

Similar to the above file, you will have to create your own federation metadata file, and provide it to Admin and ask him to register your app as Service Provider inside IdP.

How to get started with SAML in spring is given [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/).

About securing REST APIs -

1. You should add a filter to check the authentication token.
2. If token is not present, then redirect to IdP.
3. Once authentication is done, IdP will redirect back to a
   known endpoint in your application (assertion consumer endpoint)
   where you will get SAML assertion.
4. Extract this assertion to know the user details. You will have to use open SAML libraries for this.
5. Create separate session for your application, generate token or
   cookie and send it as a response. Next time, expect this token for
   each REST call.